# Fortran character arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am looking for a way to address a body of character information with two concurrent arrays in the same program unit.

For example, I want

```
CHARACTER(1) Array1(40960)
```

and

```
CHARACTER(4096) Array2(10)
```

pointing to the same body of information.

Note I have been careful in this example that the product of the dimensions and rank of the arrays are the same.

I want the solution to be `allocatable`, so I don't think `EQUIVALENCE` or `COMMON` would work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
...
character, dimension(40960), target :: array1
character(4096), dimension(:), pointer :: array2
...
call c_f_pointer (c_loc(array1), array2, [10])
```

Now, array2 points to the same storage as array1. You can make array1 allocatable if you want - in the call to c_f_pointer, the last argument is an array constructor with the dimension information for the newly assigned pointer. Don't forget the TARGET attribute on array1.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some delightfully obscure and unlikely reason, your compiler's default character kind is not the same as its C character kind, then you can also use sequence association to accomplish the same outcome as via C pointer games.  For example:

```
PROGRAM len_remapping
  IMPLICIT NONE
  CHARACTER, ALLOCATABLE, TARGET :: array1(:)
  CHARACTER(10), POINTER :: array2(:)
  INTEGER :: i

  ALLOCATE(array1(40))
  array1 = [(ACHAR(i+'A'-1), i = 1, 40)]

  CALL associate_the_pointer(  &
      array1, SIZE(array1) * LEN(array1),  &
      array2, LEN(array2) )

  PRINT "(*(A,:,1X))", array1
  PRINT "(*(A,:,1X))", array2
  PRINT *, LEN(array2), SIZE(array2)
CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE associate_the_pointer(targ, elements, ptr, ptr_length)
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: elements, ptr_length
    CHARACTER(ptr_length), INTENT(IN), TARGET :: targ(elements / ptr_length)
    CHARACTER(ptr_length), INTENT(OUT), POINTER :: ptr(:)
    ptr => targ
  END SUBROUTINE associate_the_pointer
END PROGRAM len_remapping
```

This approach has the benefit of requiring you to read some parts of the Fortran standard fifteen times over to make sure that it is conforming, and not much else.